# Градиент для одной буквы

Tags: html, css, градиент

Возникла такая проблемка: не могу реализовать градиент только для одной буквы:

[image: Сама буква и символ "!"]

Пытался реализовывать, задавая селектор и присваивая его самой букве, выделяя её тегами `<a class="grad">о!</a>`. Однако, в программе(MS FrontPage 2003) сия буква сильно выделялась и её вручную требовалось ставить на нужно место, путём перемещения блока. А в просмотре той же программы этой буквы не было вовсе:

[image: Буква в конструкторе][image: Буква в просмотре]

Может кто подскажет пути решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
  span {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 50px
  }
```

```html
Te<span>x</span>t
```